# How to close bottom sheet when swipe down?

Tags: react-native, expo

how can I close my bottom sheet when swiping down ?

I use this lib:

```
https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this enablePanDownToClose in your BottomSheet along with other properties

Comment: enablePanDownToClose not work on IOS devices.